# What's the Unix command-line symbol for "the PID of the last suspended process"?

Tags: unix, process, kill

In an interactive console like `irb`, sometimes something will go wrong and the console becomes unresponsive. One solution is to suspend the process, then kill it.

To suspend the process, I can press `Control+Z`. To kill that process, I can run `ps -ef | grep 'irb'` to list all the processes and show only the ones that contain 'irb', then get the process ID from that list and type `kill [insert PID here]`.

That's a hassle. I know that there's a way to just suspend the process, then type `kill [some symbol here]`, with the symbol representing "the last process that was suspended."

**What's the command-line symbol for "the PID of the last suspended process"?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You might be looking for the **`$!` variable** (bash manual, section *Special Parameters*).

However, you don't need the PID – the built-in `kill` command also accepts **job identifiers**, such as `%2`, which are shown when you press Ctrl-Z or type `jobs`. You can use **`%`, `%+` or `%%`** to refer to the latest job. (Other possibilities are in bash manual, section *Job Control*.)

```
>>>
[4]+  Stopped                 python
$ kill %4
```

Comment: I think `kill %` was what I was looking for. Though I suppose this is actually the last job **started** rather than the last one **suspended**, for me this is typically the same one.

Comment: @NathanLong: No, `%` is the last *suspended* job.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908610/how-to-get-pid-of-background-process

Answer (score 4):

`jobs -p %`

It shows PID of last suspended job (after pressing `Ctrl+z`).